# USB C not giving video output on Ubuntu but works on the same setup with Windows

Tags: ubuntu, display, graphics, usb-c

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. Recently I've run into a problem with my external display, which supports connecting to a device via USB C.

I'm using Lenovo Legion 5 Pro laptop and Dell P2720DC display. No external USB C adapter; just a direct connection from port to port.

When I run Windows, everything works just fine and the USB C to display connection works fine.

But when I switch to Ubuntu on dual boot, using the same connector and same cable, the display just doesn't get any input from my laptop. I can acces an USB drive, which is connected to my display's hub, but I can't get my laptop to stream any video output via the USB C port.

I've already tried to switch between integrated AMD and discrete Nvidia graphics. None of them worked.

Comment: You should add infos about the hardware you use, including the usb-c adapter

Comment: I'm using lenovo legion 5 pro laptop and dell p2720dc display. No usb-c adapter. Just directly port to port.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the Ubuntu-focused SE site: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).